# Will the 32 inch monitor from a 2006 Mac Pro work with 2007 to 2010 Mac Pros?

Tags: mac, display

Trying to find out if the 32 inch monitor/display from a 2006 Mac Pro( 1.1 version) will work with later 2007 to 2010 Mac Pro units.

Comment: Are you talking about the 30" DVI Cinema Display? There are 2 models listed  in MacTracker. Both are model # A1083 with order # M9179LL/A, but one is called "Late 2005." There are no 32" monitors. The Mac Pros you specify have DVI connectors, so my guess is that the monitor will connect. YMMV

Comment: @IconDaemon For the sake of accuracy: there are no APPLE 32" Monitors, and no Mac Pro 'came with' a display. But whatever display is connected to a 2006 Mac Pro is likely to work with a later 'cheesegrater' models.